# How to make left join on two un-related tables in hibernate query

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, mysqli

I am trying to write a left join in hibernate query. I am not able to finish it because the two tables have no relationship.

How to make left join query in hibernate query?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I am using criteria query try to make left join. I can't to do.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables have no relationship how do you expect to join them? They have to be related somehow.

Basically you need to join ON SOMETHING, if you just want data from both tables then you can query them separately.

Some more information is definitely warranted here.

Anywho, pretending that we have two tables `TA` and `TB`, if `TA` is connected to `TB` as a `TA.tbData` where `tbData` is a `@OneToMany` relationship, you can do something similar to:

You should have your `Root` from `TA`, let's call it here `rootTA`.

```
Join<TA, TB> fromTA = rootTA.join('tbData', JoinType.LEFT);
// your business logic here
```

Either way, this is very generic, without any code information or telling us what you tried, it means next nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DetachedCriteria that performs subquery

an example follows

```
DetachedCriteria personCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Person.class);
personCriteria.setProjection(Property.forName("id"));
personCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("personLastName", "Smith"));

Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Account.class);
criteria.add(Property.forName("personId").in(personCriteria));
```